# Comparar el resultado de una consulta SQL con un if

Tags: php

Quiero hacer una consulta SQL mediante php. Lo hago de esta manera:

```
$resultado =mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cantidad FROM platos WHERE nombre = 'Bagre'");
$row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
```

Y obtengo el resultado mediante `echo $row['cantidad'];`, pero quiero comparar esa cantidad con otra variable (la cantidad de este producto que se ha vendido) pero no sé cómo hacer el `if` debido a que casi siempre me ejecuta que la consulta es igual la cantidad vendida, sin importar cómo cambie esta última variable.

El código que uso es éste:

```
$vendido = 2 
if ($vendido = $resultado){
echo "Ya no quedarían productos";
} else if ($vendido > $resultado){  
echo "No se puede realizar la venta";  
}
```

SIEMPRE me imprime ya no quedan más productos.

Comment: El operador de igualdad ([ver documentación](http://php.net/es/language.operators.comparison)) es `==` y el de idéntico es `===`. Tu comparación sería `if ($vendido == $resultado) {`.

Comment: El igual es doble ==

Comment: Oscar debería colocar su comentario como respuesta

Comment: con $resultado no se ejecuta bien, debido a que el valor de ésta es `'SELECT cantidad FROM platos WHERE nombre = 'Bagre'` y no el número específico de la cantidad para hacer la comparación. Cómo debería llamar el if correctamente?
if ($vendido == $...?)

Comment: @DairoMorales ,  con tu último comentario entendí del todo qué problemas tenías más allá del operador de igualdad y modifiqué mi respuesta de acuerdo a eso, ¿podrías comprobar si mi respuesta satisface tus dudas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu `if` da siempre `true` porque se está evaluando el valor que has introducido en la variable `$vendido` a través del operador asignación `=` ([ver documentación](http://php.net/es/language.operators.assignment)). Al ser un objeto/recurso se realiza una conversión de tipo objeto > booleano ([ver documentación](http://php.net/es/language.types.boolean#language.types.boolean.casting)) que da como resultado siempre `true` (antiguamente, en PHP 4, ocurría sólo si el objeto tenía variables miembro).

Por otro lado, el operador de igualdad ([ver documentación](http://php.net/es/language.operators.comparison)) es `==` y el de idéntico es `===` (igualdad en valor y tipo de dato).

Además, quieres comparar el contenido de un registro almacenado en `$row['cantidad']` con el valor almacenado en `$vendido`, por lo que debes usar ese valor en la comparación y no el recurso de la consulta.

Tu comparación, en PHP, debería ser:

```
<?php
$vendido = 2;
if ($vendido == $row['cantidad']) {
  echo "Ya no quedarían productos";
} else if ($vendido > $resultado) {  
  echo "No se puede realizar la venta";  
}
```